# Dealing with toxic people in islam

Tags: practical-islam

I tripped and hurt someone by accident. He demanded loads of money or jail.
In this situation or in any general situation,when you get in trouble is it OK to tell a lie in Islam?
If you won't you and your family will be in trouble.

Comment: Seeking an Islamic quote or references relates to bad situations when lying seems the right thing to do.Not seeking any advice about my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample answer. If you have better answers, please add. My son wrote this:
If your intentions are good and you lie to save yourself like lying to a robber, it is permissible. He has heard a saying but cannot recall.